# Parse.com query limit

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Simple query:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.limit(1);

query.count().then(function(count) {
    console.log(count); //11
});
```

Returns count as 11.

Am I using limit wrong?

Comment: it looks like you are getting 1 count value back, what's the problem?

Comment: @dandavis no i'm getting 11 back, not 1.

Comment: but the "11" is a single result, i don't think limit and count work together like you think, i think the limit is applied after the count, so you're limiting it to a single count, but counts are always single anyway... you can tell by the promise that order of specification is not important...

Comment: what would be the point of counting the limit anyway, you might as well just give "1" to the promise callback at that point. if you want to tell if there are any users or not, an unfiltered count will perform very fast, so there's no need to limit it to optimize the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`query.count()` will return a promise for the *number of objects that satisfy that query*.  No matter what limit is set, count will count the number of objects matching the criteria.

`query.limit(N).find()` will return a promise for up to N objects that satisfy the query.  No matter how many objects satisfy the query (unless it is < N), with the limit set, it will return (up to) N objects.

Answer (score 0):

The following example is from parse.com. Try to use it and I hope that it will work correctly:

```
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
query.limit(1);
query.count({
  success: function(count) {
    // The count request succeeded. Show the count
    alert("Sean has played " + count + " games");
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // The request failed
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there a parse.com example that sets limit on a query where only count is run?  Surprising, because it would be superfluous unless a find was done afterwards (e.g. paging).